# Why is it possible to convert a file just by renaming its extension?

Tags: files, file-format, rename, format-conversion

When you rename files with a different extension, most of the time it does not work. But, if you have a .png file, you can just rename `image.png` to `image.jpeg` or `image.gif`, and it automatically gets converted to the other format and works perfectly fine. Is there some similarity between these formats which allows this to be done? I noticed this a few years back, and got interested when I was trying to convert a `.dvi` file to a `.pdf` file; just renaming it worked!

Comment: `png` to `jpeg` doesn't work in my system. The format is completely different. Are you sure that happens in ubuntu!! :O

Comment: No, there is absolutely no similarity whatsoever between gif and jpeg.  You cannot simply rename any of the files to convert them, except by using an app which does it for you.  For example, saving a gif file as jpeg in something like Gimp will convert it; renaming it on a command line will not.

Comment: I am renaming from the command line, and yes, it does work. I am using Ubuntu only, and I remember it working even on Windows.

Comment: What about `dvi` and `pdf`? Are there similarities between those two?

Comment: NO , it doesn't get converted by Simply renaming, since  `.jpg .jpeg .png` have same Default Image Viewer , it opens them. Try changing the Default Viewer for `.jpg or .png` and try opening them , you will get the difference.

Comment: Reading this a few months later, I feel very foolish asking this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is what probably happens. The application designated to open files with the file types you mention, is the same across all of those. .gif, .jpg, .png: these are all handled by [EOG (GNOME's Eye Of Gnome)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome). I suspect this application does not determine the file type based on the extension, rather it seeks for the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).

Note that the behavior of EOG may very well be exceptional, and also beware that no actual conversion is done. It's just that Linux applications tend to rely on different detection methods than file extensions, though many modern desktops actually look for the file extension to determine what application to open, since this method is probably quicker.

This all may apply to Ubuntu, Windows is a completely different story. Explorer practices a behavior by default that cuts off the file extension from the filename. This way, a file named "document.pdf" will show as "document", and renaming it to "document.dvi" will actually be processed as "document.dvi.pdf". Viruses sometimes exploit this "feature" by making the user believe they are opening a .jpg, while in reality they are being tricked into running a malicious exe!

To be really sure about filetypes, there is a command called `file` that shows you detailed file information.

From my personal experience, I can tell that, at least on my system, EOG cannot be tricked into recognizing a renamed image file. You must be doing something different than I do.

Comment: This worked even on Windows, and I think it does get converted. Once, I was trying the convert a `bmp` to `jpeg` to reduce the file size, and just renaming it worked.
And before I made EOG the default application, I was using Gwenview (KDE).
And anyway, the default application shouldn't have any effect on file management, should it?

Comment: I used Windows XP, and I always had the file type shown. Anyway, I guess that does make sense. Thanks! And I did not know about that Windows feature of cutting file extensions ... Good thing I use Ubuntu now ;) And thanks for the information about magic numbers. I knew what they were, but didn't know they were called "magic numbers"

Comment: neither windows nor ubuntu convert files just by renaming them - an overly smart program is just ignoring the extension completely when loading the file.

Answer (score 12):

Renaming `.png` files to `.jpeg` and `.gif` works because the program associated with and assigned to open those files is the same, and when it sees the extensions it can open, it simply opens them, because those are all image files and the program can open them.

The default program is EOG (Eye of Gnome) as another answerer says. Even if you remove the extension, it can still open them.

As for the `dvi` and `pdf`, again both file types are opened by the same program, which is called evince. So, the same thing happens there.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a file conversion taking place automatically. Most likely, the application used worked around the problem or an application automatically converted the file.

On the command line, you can also use `file` to give some basic information about the file, e.g.

```
cp test.png test.png.jpg
file test.png.jpg
```

Output:

```
test.png.jpg: PNG image data, 557 x 237, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

See the [`file` manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/file.1.html):

```
man file
```

You can use `convert` (it's in the package `imagemagick` or rather `imagemagick-6.q16`) or some other tool to convert the file.

```
convert test.png test.jpg
file test.jpg
```

Output:

```
test.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 557x237, components 3
```

Some tools may not be affected by the "wrong" file extensions (because they ignore them) as explained in the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/166604/618353), but I would not rely on this to always work.

---

Tip: Using `file` you can create a simple script to search for files with the wrong file format.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some similarity between these formats which allows this to be done?

Although some similarities exist between the two file formats, the main point is that the extension in the filename does not always represent the filetype its describing.
In Linux this is a given since you always specify the program you want to open your file with.

You can even check if there really is any difference between the two files comparing them using the GNU `cmp` utility together with the `--verbose --bytes=100` options to limit and view the differing bytes. I also encourage you to display the header on your terminal through `less` to not overflow it, or even better, `head -c 100` to only view the first 100 bytes to get a grasp of what `cmp` and your OS is actually reading. Neither in Ubuntu nor Windows I've been able to spot a difference. Using Paint on Windows to save a PNG to JPG format indeed changed the header from PNG to JFIF, and subsequently its contents.

I'm personally more familiar with the Windows filesystem. The extension is there so the OS can identify faster the program it is associated with, and can be modified by the user by choosing default program when selecting "Open with..." on the context menu. You can also view all the extensions Windows recognizes from the programs it has installed by launching `regedit` and navigating to `HKCR\.txt` to investigate how Windows perceives the "txt" file extension. I've personally used the Registry Editor to add the string `Content Type` with value `text/plain` to different extensions to be able to preview the text contents of a file on the Windows File Explorer's Preview Pane.

Please don't hate on me for talking about Windows. I just thought it was interesting to point out since many Windows users don't know the inner working of their Windows machine.

Comment: Ubuntu associates file extensions with default programs for each extension.